# Merging multi-dimentional arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation

How would I go about and merge a few multidimentional arrays to one large one, using C#?

How things are set up right now i eventually get one large 2d-array that holds a a few other 2d-arrays, and I need a good way to piece the arrays together.

To explain a bit better i have one array: 
Object[,] largeArray

and each Object hold another array:
Grid[,] smallArray

And I want to create a large grid from the content in the smallArrays, keeping the position they had in the largeArray. So the grid at largeArray[0, 1] would be placed right above largeArray[0, 0] and so on.

Clarification:
If the largeArray is:

```
[[A, B], 
[C, D]]
```

where A is:

```
[[a, a], 
[a, a]]
```

(And so on) the result I want should then look like this:

```
[[a, a, b, b], 
[a, a, b, b], 
[c, c, d, d], 
[c, c, d, d]]
```

The resulting Grid[,] will have the exact same size as all the small ones combined. I know that i could loop through every single element and add them individually, but is there a better way? Seeing as they already are aligned correctly in the smaller grids.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: What if values collide in the small arrays? Overwrite?

Comment: that won't be an issue. lets say that the large array is:
`[[A, B],
 [C, D]]`

where A is: 
`[[a, a],
 [a, a]]`
(And so on)

the result I want should then look like this:
`[[a, a, b, b],
 [a, a, b, b],
 [c, c, d, d],
 [c, c, d, d]]`

Hope that makes sense =)

Comment: Don't put elaboration, code, or example data in the comments. Edit your question so that it's a better question. While you're at it, fix the question so that it's clear. Tell us what research you've already done, what code you've already written, tell us exactly what problems you're having with that code. Show a clear example of an input to the code, and state clearly what the output should be given that input. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Barring an improved question: are you saying that the dimensions of your final, large `Grid[,]` are always going to be the sum of the dimensions of the smaller `Grid[,]` objects contained in your `Object[,]` array? Will each member of the `Object[,]` array have the same dimensions, or can they vary?

Comment: updated the original question with some clarification, thanks!